# how can I order my SQL query by the next-in-line parent's ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called stages like this:

| stageID | stage | parentStageID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage1 | NULL |
| 2 | Stage2 | 3 |
| 3 | Substage1 | 1 |
| 4 | Stage3 | 2 |

The parentStageID references the stageID of its parent in the same table. I'm trying to write a query that selects everything in the table and sorts them by order of the next child in line. The NULL parentStageID being the first in the sequence, followed by the next stage with parentStageID equal to the last stageID.

The ordered table results like this:

| stageID | stage | parentStageID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage1 | NULL |
| 3 | Substage1 | 1 |
| 2 | Stage2 | 3 |
| 4 | Stage3 | 2 |

I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this, but from other similar stack posts I was trying to do this with:

```
SELECT * FROM stages ORDER BY COALESCE(`parentStageID`, `stageID`), `parentStageID` IS NOT NULL, `stageID`;
```

Here I have this small [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b6492/1) on SQL fiddle

as you can see this query is resulting as:

| stageID | stage | parentStageID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage1 | NULL |
| 3 | Substage1 | 1 |
| 4 | Stage3 | 2 |
| 2 | Stage2 | 3 |

Appreciate any ideas on the type of query I need for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive d(id, stage, pid) as (
   select * from demo where parentstageid is null
   union all
   select d2.* from d d1 join demo d2 on d1.id = d2.parentstageid
)
select * from d;
```

Output:

| id | stage | pid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stage1 | null |
| 3 | Substage1 | 1 |
| 2 | Stage2 | 3 |
| 4 | Stage3 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is quite a tricky question, your data is similar to a companies employee data we can say for example:

```
Employee 1 has Employee 3 as his higher up
Employee 3 is the highest level in company
Employee 2 has Employee 1 as his higher up
```

what you need is to order employee based on their level in company, highest first then level below it and so on

```
Employee 3
Employee 1  , Employee 3
Employee 2  , Employee 1
```

Considering this above scenario, I tried to create a T-SQL code hope it helps:

```
-- Getting all data in seprate table 
-- Indi column added to tell if that record is processed or not for ordering
-- Ord column added to give order for final output
select *,ParentStageid as dummy, 0 ord, 0 indi
into #test
from stage

Declare @pstageID int = 0
Declare @order int = 1

-- while loop which will run through each record
while exists(select * from #test where indi = 0)
begin
      update #test 
      set ord = @order, indi = 1 ,@pstageID = stageID
      where dummy is null and indi = 0

      Update #test
      set dummy = null 
      where parentStageID = @pstageID

      set @order = 1 + @order
end

-- Final Output as asked
select * from #test 
order by ord
```

Output:

[image]

This code might not be best for huge data, but it will give the expected output.